# mysql search comma list of number ranges

Tags: mysql, sql, select

In one of my tables fields I contain age ranges. They would be in a format such as

```
27-51,18-28,10-17
37-55,60-70
1-5,11-16,30-32,60-90
etc
```

I'm trying to build a SELECT statement where I can search if my given age falls into any of the ranges... something such as

```
SELECT * from table where age IN (1-5,11-16,30-32,60-90)
```

However it would search within the given ranges

I can do it if I only have one range using something like...

```
WHERE age 
BETWEEN
SUBSTRING_INDEX(personsAge,"-",1) + 0 AND
SUBSTRING_INDEX(personsAge,"-",-1) + 0
```

but how can I accomplish this if I have multiple ranges?

Comment: This is bad data design, you should not have a column with multiple values in there with the commas seperating the values.  They should have different row in a table to join on.  Also should probably have 2 columns one for min and one for max age

Comment: Let this be a lesson to design your tables properly.  Problem that is supposed to be easy become extremely complicated because of messed up design.

Comment: The other comments already said what needed to be said. Regarding your question: If you are allowed to create a userdefined function to parse the content of the column and compare the value against it, then that will probably be your best chance. Write your function, then use `select * from table where MyFunction_IsInRange(column_with_ranges, age) = 1`. (And yes, this kind of design should not be encouraged, but I'll just assume that this wasn't the OP's idea.)

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer extending my comment above.
I'm assuming that you can create a function:

**Attention**: This is for `Sql Anywhere`. Please adjust the syntax for `MySql` (especially the `locate`-function where the parameters are switched). The code is not production ready and I left out some validity checks. I'm assuming that the values in the column are all well formatted.

**Attention 2**: This is one of those cases where someone dumps a terrible database design on you and demands that you solve the problem. Please avoid creating the need for solutions like this.

Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION "DBA"."is_in_range"(age_range varchar(255), age int)
returns int
begin 
  declare pos int;
  declare pos2 int;
  declare strPart varchar(50);
  declare strFrom varchar(10);
  declare strTo varchar(10);
  declare iFrom int;
  declare iTo int;

  while 1 = 1 loop
    set pos = locate(age_range, ',');
    if pos = 0 then
      -- no comma found in the rest of the column value -> just take the whole string
      set strPart = age_range;
    else 
      -- take part of the sting until next comma
      set strPart = substr(age_range, 1, pos - 1);
    end if;
    -- we are parsing the min-max part and do some casting to compare with an int
    set pos2 = locate(strPart, '-');
    set strFrom = substr(strPart, 1, pos2 - 1);
    set strTo = substr(strPart, pos2 + 1);
    set iFrom = cast(strFrom as int);
    set iTo = cast(strTo as int);

    if age between iFrom and iTo then
      return 1;
    end if;
    -- if at end of age_range then quit
    if pos = 0 then
      return 0;
    end if;
    -- get the next part of the string after the comma
    set age_range = substr(age_range, pos + 1);
    set pos = locate(age_range, ',', pos);
  end loop;

  return 0;
end;
```

Test data:

```
create local temporary table #tmpRanges (ident int, age_range varchar(255));
insert into #tmpRanges (ident, age_range) values (1, '27-51,18-28,10-17');
insert into #tmpRanges (ident, age_range) values (2, '37-55,60-70');
insert into #tmpRanges (ident, age_range) values (3, '1-5,11-16,30-32,60-90');
insert into #tmpRanges (ident, age_range) values (4, '1-50');
```

Call:

```
select * from #tmpRanges where is_in_range(age_range, 51) = 1;
select * from #tmpRanges where is_in_range(age_range, 10) = 1;
select * from #tmpRanges where is_in_range(age_range, 9) = 1;
etc...
```